# How to integrate d3.js chart in C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, d3.js

I am a big fan of Mike Bostock's d3.js chart library: d3js.org.

I would like to use it to display charts in a C# .Net application, but I don't know if it is possible.

It may be possible by generating HTM+JS codes and rendering it in a webbrowser window.
However, I understood d3.js library cannot be used locally without a webserver (However I did not understood what works without a webserver and what requires a webserver), therefore a simple solution does not work.

Has anybody tried to develop that kind of deployment of d3.js charts?
Do you have an idea on where to start in order to have the most simple solution?

Comment: Best guesses I can say are, have a node.js server local and mock up the web browser dependencies of his library so it can generate the svg and then have your C# request the svg and use something like this http://harriyott.com/2008/05/converting-svg-images-to-png-in-c.aspx to turn the SVG into something that winforms can render. alternatively you may also be able to use something like http://sourceforge.net/p/netsvgtogdi/home/Home/ but I think you'll be SOL regarding executing that javascript in .net, best bet would be a local node server spitting it to svg on disk.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A web server definitely isn't required to use a client side JavaScript library like d3.js.

For C#, you'll need to embed a web browser control (in either WindowsForms or WPF).

You'll need to make sure that the browser is working in IE9 Standards mode as shown [here](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1720).

Create your web pages as you would normally. Navigate to them using webbrowser.navigate (as just files on the file system.)

This should work.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your answer.
Actually it can work without a web server. There are however limitations when I need to import data from external files in json or csv formats. I need to find a way to make this work locally.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Embedded web browsers are allowed to read files from the file system.

Comment: D3 loads files via XMLHttpRequest, which is prevented in modern browsers from loading local files. The only workaround I've come up with is to have my app write the data into a .js file (as json) and then include that file in my d3 html page with the a <script> tag.

Comment: D3 doesn't need to be at all involved with file loading. It's not an opinionated library that forces any particular method. If you've created a local embedded application, it's easy in C# to build a tiny embedded web server if it's necessary for a complete experience.

Answer (score 12):

Necromancing.

You can do this with C# and .NET-Core on all operating systems using nodeJS.
Absolutely no browser-control required. 
Just install [JavaScript-Services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) with nuget, then install d3, jsdom and svg2png in nodejs:

```
npm install –save svg2png
npm install –save jsdom
npm install –save d3
```

then in Startup.cs, add NodeServices in ConfigureServices

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      // services.AddMvc();

      // https://geeks.ms/clanderas/2016/10/18/asp-net-core-node-services-to-execute-your-nodejs-scripts/
      // https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/
      services.AddNodeServices( options => {
      // options.DebuggingPort 
      });
}
```

Add an output handler:

```
public class AgeInfo
{

    public string age;
    public int population;

    public AgeInfo(string prmAge, int prmPop)
    {
        this.age = prmAge;
        this.population = prmPop;
    }

}


// http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/10/aspnet-core-node-d3js/
public async Task<IActionResult> Chart([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
{
    var options = new { width = 400, height = 200 };

    var data = new[] {
        new { label = "Abulia", count = 10 },
        new { label = "Betelgeuse", count = 20 },
        new { label = "Cantaloupe", count = 30 },
        new { label = "Dijkstra", count = 40 }
    };

    List<AgeInfo> ls = new List<AgeInfo>();
    ls.Add( new AgeInfo("<5", 2704659));
    ls.Add( new AgeInfo("5-13", 4499890));
    ls.Add( new AgeInfo("14-17", 2159981));
    ls.Add( new AgeInfo("18-24", 3853788));
    ls.Add( new AgeInfo("25-44", 14106543));
    ls.Add( new AgeInfo("45-64", 8819342));
    ls.Add( new AgeInfo("≥65", 612463));


    // string markup = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<string>("Node/d3Pie.js", options, data);

    string markup = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<string>("Node/d3chart.js", options, ls);

    string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset=""utf-8"" />
<style type=""text/css"">
.arc text 
{
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
.arc path 
{
  stroke: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src=""" + markup + @""" />
</body>
</html>";

    return Content(html, "text/html");
}
```

And then add the JavaScript

```
// Include all modules we need
const svg2png = require("svg2png");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const d3 = require('d3');



// https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235
module.exports = function (callback, options, data) {


    var dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head><body><svg width="960" height="500"></svg></body></html>');
    var document = dom.window.document;
    dom.window.d3 = d3.select(dom.window.document);


    // callback(null, dom.window.document.body.innerHTML);


    var svg = dom.window.d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");



    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    var pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) {
            return d.population;
        });


    var path = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(0);

    var label = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 40)
        .innerRadius(radius - 40);

    /*
    var dataaa =
        [
            {
                age: "<5",
                population: 2704659
            },
            {
                age: "5-13",
                population: 4499890
            },
            {
                age: "14-17",
                population: 2159981
            },
            {
                age: "18-24",
                population: 3853788
            },
            {
                age: "25-44",
                population: 14106543
            }
            ,
            {
                age: "45-64",
                population: 8819342
            }
            ,
            {
                age: "≥65",
                population: 612463
            }
        ];
    */

        var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    arc.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.data.age);
        });

    arc.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.data.age;
        });
    //});

    // var svgText = dom.window.document.body.outerHTML;
    // var svgText = dom.window.document.body.innerHTML;
    var svgText = dom.window.document.body.querySelector("svg").outerHTML
    // callback(null, svgText);

    // var svgText = dom.window.d3.select("svg").html();
    // svgText=process.version; // v8.6.0
    // svgText= JSON.stringify(process.versions); //
    // var pjson = require('./package.json'); svgText = pjson.version;
    // callback(null, svgText);
    // callback(null, JSON.stringify(  { width: width, height: height } ));

    // var buf = Buffer.from(svgText);
    // callback(null, JSON.stringify( buf ));
    // var output = svg2png.sync(buf, { width: width, height: height } );
    // callback(null, JSON.stringify( output ));
    //callback(null,  svgText);
    // callback(null,  'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + Buffer.from(svgText).toString('base64'));


    svg2png(Buffer.from(svgText), { width: width, height: height })
        .then(buffer => 'data:image/png;base64,' + buffer.toString('base64') )
        .then(buffer => callback(null, buffer));

}
```

That should give you a the required d3-chart without needing a svg-compatible browser.

You might need to update npm before you can (successfully) install any nodeJS modules.

```
npm install -g npm
```

You can also do this in a command-line application, just that then you need to set up your own DI contrainer.

Comment: What kind of render speed would you expect from this on a decent desktop? Is the render speed sufficient to host interactive graphs this way - passing mouse coordinates to node and letting it render at >30fps?

Comment: Self Answer: Found this which indicated a svg2png render speed around 2-3 seconds which would not be suitable for interaction (and also too slow compared to a hosted browser)

Comment: @Rick Love: You only need the PNG when you can't display the SVG to the browser, that is to say for IE <= 8, which should be extinct by now. You can also render the SVG to png with C#, if you find a suitable renderer, which you most-likely won't.

Comment: You forgot to credit your source https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-node-d3js/

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for the same solution and stumbled on [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#scripting-nodejs-from-clr). It can be run from any .NET 4.5 application and installed via Nuget. It doesn't require node.js installed but you will need node to install D3 using NPM. Make sure `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder is in the same directory as the `edge.js` file at runtime, or installed globally. 
I just ran `npm i d3-array` from inside the `\edge` folder, then included the *.json and *.js files, set them to content and copy to output directory. Then its as simple as:

```
class Program {
    public static async Task Start(int[] someArray) {
        var func = Edge.Func(@"
            var d3 = require('d3-array')
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, 'D3 says: ' + d3.min(data));
            }
        ");
        Console.WriteLine(await func(someArray));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Start(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }).Wait();
    }
}
```

Outputs: `D3 says: 1`

NOTE: In .Net7.2 i had to install the `Edge.Js.Binaries` NuGet package to install the edge folder in the project root. The `Edge.Js` package didn't do this, in 4.5 it did.